# The entity type 'ModeratedUser' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, database-migration

I am experiencing an error with `AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` 2.1.6 using code-first database migrations. The error is

> The entity type 'ModeratedUser' requires a primary key to be defined.

This is confusing me as I have a primary key defined for all entities using Fluent Api. I have done research on this specific issue and all posts I have ran across are referring to different issues (Please note that I have followed the following for defining my many-to-many relationship: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration)

Here are the entities and the entity type configurations:

```
public class ModeratedUser
{
    public Guid ModeratedId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ModeratorModerated> ModeratorModerated { get; set; }
}

public class ModeratorUser
{
    public Guid ModeratorId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ModeratorModerated> ModeratorModerated { get; set; }
}

//explicit class to outline many to many between moderated and moderators
public class ModeratorModerated
{
    public Guid ModeratorId { get; set; }
    public Guid ModeratedId { get; set; }
    public ModeratedUser Moderated { get; set; }
    public ModeratorUser Moderator { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the entity type configurations:

```
public abstract class ModeratedConfiguration : EntityMappingConfiguration<ModeratedUser>
{
    public override void MapToConfig(EntityTypeBuilder<ModeratedUser> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.ModeratedId);

        builder.ToTable("ModeratedUsers", "Mod");
    }
}

public abstract class ModeratorsConfiguration : EntityMappingConfiguration<ModeratorUser>
{
    public override void MapToConfig(EntityTypeBuilder<ModeratorUser> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.ModeratorId);
        builder.ToTable("ModeratorUsers", "Mod");
    }
}

public abstract class ModeratorModeratedConfiguration : EntityMappingConfiguration<ModeratorModerated>
{
    public override void MapToConfig(EntityTypeBuilder<ModeratorModerated> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => new { x.ModeratedId, x.ModeratorId });

        builder.HasOne(x => x.Moderated)
            .WithMany(x => x.ModeratorModerated)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ModeratedId);

        builder.HasOne(x => x.Moderator)
            .WithMany(x => x.ModeratorModerated)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ModeratorId);

        builder.ToTable("ModeratorModerated", "Mod");
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have set the .HasKey for both the ModeratorUser.cs and ModeratedUser.cs and have set the CompositeKey for the ModeratorModerated.cs configuration class.

Here's my Context class:

```
public class DbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbContext(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<CatalogItem> CatalogItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ModeratedUser> ModeratedUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ModeratorUser> ModeratorUsers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.HasDefaultSchema("UDC");

        builder.AddEntityConfigurationsFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

And here is my ModelBuilderExtensions.cs class that I use to instantiate the EntityMappingConfigurations...

```
public interface IEntityMappingConfiguration
{
    void MapToConfig(ModelBuilder b);
}

public interface IEntityMappingConfiguration<T> : IEntityMappingConfiguration where T : class
{
    void MapToConfig(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder);
}

public abstract class EntityMappingConfiguration<T> : IEntityMappingConfiguration<T> where T : class
{
    public abstract void MapToConfig(EntityTypeBuilder<T> b);

    public void MapToConfig(ModelBuilder b)
    {
        MapToConfig(b.Entity<T>());
    }
}

public static class ModelBuilderExtenions
{
    private static IEnumerable<Type> GetMappingTypes(this Assembly assembly, Type mappingInterface)
    {
        return assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => !x.IsAbstract && x.GetInterfaces().Any(y => y.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType && y.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == mappingInterface));
    }

    public static void AddEntityConfigurationsFromAssembly(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, Assembly assembly)
    {
        var mappingTypes = assembly.GetMappingTypes(typeof(IEntityMappingConfiguration<>));
        foreach (var config in mappingTypes.Select(Activator.CreateInstance).Cast<IEntityMappingConfiguration>())
        {
            config.MapToConfig(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

The error coming from the PackageManagerConsole window in VS2017 is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'ModeratedUser' requires a primary key to be defined.

As you can see, small app but I can't get past my first m-m using EFCore. This wasn't nearly as challenging in EF6.2. What am I missing here?

Comment: **abstract** configuration classes - cannot be instantiated, hence the configuration code is not called.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I've added my ModelBuilderExtension class which instantiates the abstracts classes. 

This approach worked fine with other entities that I have removed from the DBContext class for brevity. I am struggling specifically with the entities listed above for some unknown reason. 

Nice catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this changes

```
public class ModeratedConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ModeratedUser>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ModeratedUser> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("ModeratedUsers", "Mod");
        builder.HasKey(x => x.ModeratedId);
    }
}

public class ModeratorsConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ModeratorUser>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ModeratorUser> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("ModeratorUsers", "Mod");
        builder.HasKey(x => x.ModeratorId);
    }
}

public class ModeratorModeratedConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ModeratorModerated>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ModeratorModerated> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("ModeratorModerated", "Mod");
        builder.HasKey(x => new { x.ModeratedId, x.ModeratorId });

        builder.HasOne(x => x.Moderated)
            .WithMany(x => x.ModeratorModerated)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ModeratedId);

        builder.HasOne(x => x.Moderator)
            .WithMany(x => x.ModeratorModerated)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ModeratorId);

    }
}
```

Your DbContext should be

```
public class DbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

    public DbContext(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<CatalogItem> CatalogItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ModeratedUser> ModeratedUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ModeratorUser> ModeratorUsers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.HasDefaultSchema("UDC");

        builder.ApplyConfiguration<ModeratedUser>(new ModeratedUser());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration<ModeratedUser>(new ModeratorsConfiguration());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration<ModeratorModerated>(new ModeratorModeratedConfiguration());
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```